# How to render different path shapes based on property in viewmodel

Tags: wpf, mvvm, path, styles, datatrigger

I have a viewmodel that exposes an observablecollection of type Activity. Each Activity has a property named ActivityType.

In my View I have an ItemsControl of which the ItemsPanelTemplate is a Canvas. I bind the ItemsControl's itemsource property to the observablecollection in the view. Each Activity in the observablecollection must be rendered in the view as a wpf path object that looks different based on the ActivityType property of each Activity in the observablecollection.

If I define a set of styles in my View's resources section for each path I want to display, how do I create a different Path object on the canvas based on the ActivityType property on each Activity?

Do I used DataTraiggers in a DataTemplate?

The XAML for the view is as follows:
    
        DarkBlue

```
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ItemBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
        <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
            <GradientStop Color="#FAFBE9" Offset="0" />
            <GradientStop Color="Blue" Offset="1" />
        </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
    </LinearGradientBrush>

    <Style x:Key="FlowChartItemStyle" TargetType="Path">
        <Setter Property="Fill" Value="{StaticResource ItemBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="{StaticResource ItemStroke}"/>
        <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="StrokeLineJoin" Value="Round"/>
        <Setter Property="Stretch" Value="Fill"/>
        <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="50"/>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="50"/>
    </Style>

    <!-- Process -->
    <Style x:Key="Process" TargetType="Path" BasedOn="{StaticResource FlowChartItemStyle}">
        <Setter Property="Data" Value="M 0,0 H 60 V40 H 0 Z"/>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="Process_DragThumb" TargetType="Path" BasedOn="{StaticResource Process}">
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="30"/>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="30"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5,5,5,5"/>
    </Style>

    <!-- Decision -->
    <Style x:Key="Decision" TargetType="Path" BasedOn="{StaticResource FlowChartItemStyle}">
        <Setter Property="Data" Value="M 0,20 L 30 0 L 60,20 L 30,40 Z"/>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="Decision_DragThumb" TargetType="Path" BasedOn="{StaticResource Decision}">
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="30"/>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="30"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5,5,5,5"/>
        <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="Decision"/>
    </Style>

    <!-- Start -->
    <Style x:Key="Start" TargetType="Path" BasedOn="{StaticResource FlowChartItemStyle}">
        <Setter Property="Data" Value="M 10,20 A 20,20 0 1 1 50,20 A 20,20 0 1 1 10,20"/>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="Start_DragThumb" TargetType="Path" BasedOn="{StaticResource Start}">
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="30"/>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="30"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5,5,5,5"/>
    </Style>

    <!-- Terminator -->
    <Style x:Key="Terminator" TargetType="Path" BasedOn="{StaticResource FlowChartItemStyle}">
        <Setter Property="Data" Value="M 20,40 A 20,20 0 0 1 20,0 H 40 A 20,20 0 0 1 40,40 Z"/>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="Terminator_DragThumb" TargetType="Path" BasedOn="{StaticResource Terminator}">
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="30"/>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="30"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5,5,5,5"/>
    </Style>        
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding CanvasActivities}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Canvas/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style>
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Path=Top}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Path=Left}"/>
                </Style>
            </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Value="0" Binding="{Binding Path=ActivityType}">

                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Value="1" Binding="{Binding Path=ActivityType}">

                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Value="2" Binding="{Binding Path=ActivityType}">

                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Value="3" Binding="{Binding Path=ActivityType}">

                        </DataTrigger>
                    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Comment: You should be using a DataTemplateSelector

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to use `ItemsControl.ItemTemplateSelector` with your own `DataTemplateSelector` class - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplateselector.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector.aspx for more information.

Then you'd have a seperate `DataTemplate` for each different path you are showing.

Comment: Thanks, but if I undertand the samples in the links you've given me correctly, the datatemplateselector class must be aware of elements in your view as well as entities in your viewmodel. Will that not break the MVVM pattern?

Comment: Not necessarily - your view must always be aware of your viewmodel anyway, in order to bind to properties on it. The viewmodel will still have no knowledge of the view, the templates, or anything else. Think of a DataTemplateSelector similar to IValueConverter, which usually needs to understand the viewmodel and formats data specifically for a view.

Comment: In the above code, what if I need to add a label inside the component.. say inside Process component, I need a label which shows Process on that.

Comment: Can you put a label in your datatemplate? I'm not really sure what the context is for your question...